# sparse matrix tocoo() ValueError: Buffer has wrong number of dimensions (expected 1, got 2)

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

This is the code, I don't know why it get error.
x and y are the same type, y can execute y.tocoo() but x can't.
When I execute this code on the google colab, it has no error.
can you help me?

```
ipdb> x = scipy.sparse.lil_matrix(y.shape)
ipdb> x.rows = preds_k
ipdb> x.data = np.ones_like(preds_k)
ipdb> x
<4217x1018 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 84340 stored elements in List of Lists format>
ipdb> y
<4217x1018 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 13037 stored elements in List of Lists format>
ipdb> x.shape
(4217, 1018)
ipdb> y.shape
(4217, 1018)
ipdb> x.tocoo()
*** ValueError: Buffer has wrong number of dimensions (expected 1, got 2)
ipdb> y.tocoo()
<4217x1018 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 13037 stored elements in COOrdinate format>
```

Thank you.

Comment: .tell us about `preds_k`

Comment: Look at `y.rows` and `y.data`.  Do the `x` values that you set look the same?  They should be object arrays of lists.  `ones_like` doesn't do that.

Comment: @hpaulj y.data is `array([list([1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]), list([1.0]),
       list([1.0, 1.0]), ..., list([1.0, 1.0]), list([1.0, 1.0]),
       list([1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0])], dtype=object)`, and x.data is the normal array.

Comment: @hpaulj can u tell me how to create the object arrays of lists like y.data, thank u.

Comment: Generally we don't create a `lil` matrix by assigning values to the `rows` and `data` attributes, as you attempt to do here.  We let the `lil` constructor do that.  `lil` is intended for relatively efficient iterative assignment.  We use `coo` format  to construct the matrix from arrays of row/col/data.